# How to set PHP configuration directives in php.ini through the command line

Tags: php

Trying to make a user data script for an AWS EC2 that will set php configuration directives but having no luck.

Tried using the --define (-d) php option but just sits there until I control c out of it.

```
[ec2-user@ip ~]$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php.d/20-bz2.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini

[ec2-user@ip ~]$ php -i | grep length
session.sid_length => 224 => 224

[ec2-user@ip ~]$ php -d session.sid_length=220
^C
```

I expected the command to run then if I look at the configuration for session sid length again it would be updated to 220.

Comment: `-d` [options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) just apply temporarily, for the invocation they're used with.

Comment: Cant you just edit the ini file?  `vi php.ini` and change what you require?

Comment: @mario thank you, makes sense now why it wasn't working.

Comment: @Nic3500 is there a way do to use vi/vim from a bash script to do that?  I've been looking into using sed to it, but wouldn't be opposed to using vi if I could.

Comment: From a script, no.  I am suprised that the only thing available to you is a bash script.  That script has to run in something right?  You do not have access to that?

Comment: @Nic3500 I do have access to a bash shell to run vi/vim in, but I am trying cut down on most if not all manual editing that is needed to configure the server. Trying to accomplish this through a launch script (user data on aws) that is automatically run for me when the ec2 instance is launch.

Answer (score 0):

As @mario pointed out above -d (--define) only works for the invocation they are used with.  But found a way to edit any doc from the command line using sed (stream editor).  For example:

```
sed -i 's/session.sid_bits_per_character = [0-9]/session.sid_bits_per_character = 6/g' /etc/php.ini

# Format
sed -i 's/find/replace/g' path_to_file
```